# trigger from out side this slider, which has two way trigger,

Tags: jquery

This slider has two way trigger system.

[Slider](http://tympanus.net/Development/TripleViewLayout/)
 its slide left and right.
I like to trigger this slider from outside of the slider.

how to slide left and right, from out side of the slider.

```
  $("#left").click(function (e) {
    $(".vs-nav-left").trigger("click");
});

$("#right").click(function (e) {
    $(".vs-nav-right").trigger("click");
});
```

this slider has two way triggering system. one is section vice and other is link wise. i need to trigger both ways from out side divs. (# left and #right)

Comment: Show some code that you have tried till now

Comment: To add to what @NitinRawat has said: you should always provide the code you're having problems with within the question itself. Otherwise when you fix the problem on your site this question will be completely useless to any future visitors.

Comment: i need to trigger this slider from out side Div (class), using javascript.

Comment: In your code you are missing '.' before 'vs-nav-left'

Comment: this slider has two way triggering system. one is section vice and other is link wise. i need to trigger both links from out side div.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see the the left the left/right targets has a the class `vs-nav-left` and `vs-nav-right` respectively.

So the solution is to manually trigger the click event on them like

Using jQuery

```
$('.vs-nav .vs-nav-right').click()
$('.vs-nav .vs-nav-left').click()
```